# GitHub Integration

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-github-plugin

Am trying to integrate GitHub with Jenkins. I recieve the below error message, under configuration:

Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/Ajith-Raman/Sample_Repo.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Ajith-Raman/Sample_Repo.git/': Received HTTP code 404 from proxy after CONNECT

Could someone help me on this?

Kindly find below the steps followed:

1. Create ssh files with the root user. 
   i.e. C:\Users\C51539A.ssh in my case (Local VM).

   All the executions happen via Jenkins (credentials - admin/admin).
2. Copy the .ssh folder into C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\users\admin (Jenkins_Home).
   Also tried the above step, creating a new user (jenkins/jenkins).
3. Copy the public key (id_rsa.pub), to my github account (Under SSH and GPG Keys).
4. Switched remote urls from https to ssh.
   i.e. https://github.com/Ajith-Raman/Sample_Repo.git to
       git@github.com:Ajith-Raman/Sample_Repo.git in my case.
5. In Jenkins, Under Credentials 
   SSH Username with private key ---> Directly enter the private key (I believe, its the key within id_rsa).
6. Change the ownership to jenkins user (admin in my case)
   No error message was thrown. At the same time, ownership never changed. Do not understand this strange behavior.
   Note: Jenkins was restarted.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

Your steps to configure Jenkins and Git integration look weird.

My expectation is that you should use [Jenkins Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) in order to fetch your script from Github

[image: JMeter Git Plugin]

When you click `Add` button you will be able to choose different options

[image: JMeter Credentials Plugin]

The ones, which are applicable for you are:

- `Username with password` - for HTTPS URL
- `SSH username with private key` - for SSH URL

Once you provide the relevant credentials you should be able to pull the desired branch from the Github.

Check out the following materials for more information:

- [Jenkins Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin)
- [Using Credentials](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/)
- [How to Run a JMeter Test with Jenkins 2.0 Pipelines and GitHub](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-jmeter-test-jenkins-20-pipelines-and-github)

Comment: Have added few updates. Kindly go through. Your inputs are valuable.